# file zill doesn't generate ppk file

Tags: filezilla, pem

I am using file zilla 3.14.1 which allows convert ppk file from pem. I did in past. But today it didn't do it. It didn't show any message after selecting pem file. I have uninstalled, installed more than 10 times. Got same result.

Comment: Why not just use OpenSSL? http://superuser.com/questions/232362/how-to-convert-ppk-key-to-openssh-key-under-linux

Comment: @GlenSelle For which purpose you advised me to use OpenSSL

Answer (score 0):

Oh at last i got the solution from my boss. He did the job by following the procedure 
1. First add host in site manager by selecting SSH protocol and logontype: ask for password.
2. Give user name ubuntu
3. then select the pem file which converted to ppk
4. Go to site manager and select the site for connecting
5. It ask for password. but it remain blank
6. connected